# Is there a better word than "moot" for "not worth talking about"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Of course a lot of people misunderstand the primary [meaning of the adjective "moot"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moot) -- "open to question" or "argued about but not possible to prove" -- using the word only in the expression "moot point", which rightly or wrongly is often taken to mean "not worth debating".  As a result the word is apt to cause confusion, even when properly used.

So is there a better word to use for the minor meaning of "moot" -- "not worth talking about" or "no longer important or worth discussing"?  A term which might be used in the sentence "The question of what color to paint the ceiling is _____ since we won't be adding on after all"?

(One advantage of "moot" in this sense is that it's short and abrupt, which serves to enhance the meaning.  Except that the wrong meaning may still be "heard".)

Comment: Irrelevant? Stupid? Obvious? Jejune? They're all judgemental. Anything that's moot is open **only** to discussion. Cf. _moot court_. That is, it's theoretical, hypothetical, non-factual. Not to say it's not useful in training people in all sorts of skills including lawyering and politicking.

Comment: @JohnLawler - If you look at [the definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moot), the adjective "moot" has a meaning of ": not worth talking about : no longer important or worth discussing" or " :  deprived of practical significance :  made abstract or purely academic".  I'm looking for another word for that sense.

Comment: Unnecessary,  redundant, unneeded will all fit your quote. Though do side with Mr Lawler to its normal use.

Comment: If you mean that it's like a cow's opinion... it doesn't matter... then, **it's moo**.

Comment: @TusharRaj - I mean like we needed to decide about A because we were planning to do B.  Now we're no longer planning to do B, so the issue of what to do about A is ____.

Comment: @HotLicks: `Impertinent` comes to mind. But, like `moot`, this word also has a different primary sense.

Comment: `Academic` can be used to describe a topic that can be discussed, but does not have implications in reality.

Comment: I'm wondering whether  _so many people use 'moot' to mean 'academic'_ that the dictionaries should consider promoting this sense into their 'primary meaning' slots. It's certainly the sense I come across more often. (A Google search gives early hits very largely involving neither of the senses mentioned here.) Since the 'not worth talking about' sense is included in all dictionaries worth mentioning, 'rightly or wrongly' is silly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a veiled grouse.

Comment: No, there is no better word than *moot* in that sentence. Its specific meaning in that sentence cannot be in doubt. And it's hardly a 'minor meaning.' If I was straining for an alternative, I might use *[immaterial](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/immaterial)*, although it seems to suffer a similar problem with some dictionaries not quite keeping up with it.

Comment: I might try ***pointless***

Comment: No research indicated? From someone who's been here as long as you...

Comment: @Clare - What makes you say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we're better off using two words here than one

- what color to paint the ceiling is **not pertinent/germane/applicable**.

For a single word, [impertinent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/impertinent) seems to fit, but it has a primary meaning of rude.

Also consider:

- what color to paint the ceiling is **beside the point/neither here nor there.**

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the word superfluous (as in something that is off topic or simply something that does not need to be discussed).

Answer (score 0):

inconsequential

> adjective
>   Not important or significant. ‘they talked about inconsequential
>   things’
>   [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inconsequential)